# Add custom source directory?

Tags: c++, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I am new to Gradle and trying to create a cross platform build script for a C++ project.
I wish to use a custom source directory. Not `src/{ProjectName}/cpp` or `header/{ProjectName}/cpp`.
My source files are in folders named `src` and `include` at the same level as the `build.gradle` file.

Please see image of my project directory structure

[image]

How do i link to those source folders only? The gradle cpp library example does not cover this.
The script i have made builds successfully but does not produce an exe. I guess because it cant find the cpp files.

Better yet how can i see the paths being used by gradle?
options -"-info" and “–debug” don’t seem to output the source paths used.

Below is my full script…

```
apply plugin: 'cpp' 

model { 

    buildTypes {
        debug
        release
    }

    platforms {

        //osx_64 {
            //architecture "x86_64"
            //operatingSystem "osx"
        //}

        windows_x86 {
            architecture "x86"
            operatingSystem "windows"
        }

        windows_64 {
            architecture "x86_64"
            operatingSystem "windows"
        }
    }

    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) { 
            libcinder { 
                headers.srcDir "/../cinder/include/" 
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    if (targetPlatform.operatingSystem.windows) {
                        if (targetPlatform == platforms.windows_x86) {
                            if(buildType == buildTypes.debug) {
                                staticLibraryFile = file("/../cinder/lib/msw/x86/Debug/v140/cinder.lib") 
                            } else if(buildType == buildTypes.release) {
                                staticLibraryFile = file("/../cinder/lib/msw/x86/Release/v140/cinder.lib") 
                            }
                        } else if(targetPlatform == platforms.windows_64) {
                            if(buildType == buildTypes.debug) {
                                staticLibraryFile = file("/../cinder/lib/msw/x64/Debug/v140/cinder.lib") 
                            } else if(buildType == buildTypes.release) {
                                staticLibraryFile = file("/../cinder/lib/msw/x64/Release/v140/cinder.lib") 
                            }
                        } 
                    } //else if(targetPlatform.operatingSystem.o osx) {
                        //if (targetPlatform == platforms.osx_64) {
                            //if(buildType == buildTypes.debug) {
                                //staticLibraryFile = file("/../cinder/lib/macosx/Debug/libcinder.a") 
                            //} else if(buildType == buildTypes.release) {
                                //staticLibraryFile = file("/../cinder/lib/macosx/Release/libcinder.a") 
                            //}
                        //}
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    components {
        main(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
                cpp {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src"
                        include "include"
                        cpp.lib library: "libcinder", linkage: "static" 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

/*
    components {
        main(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
                cpp.lib library: "libcinder", linkage: "static" 
            }
        }
    }
*/    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **The way that this is done with a Gradle C++ project is different than the way it's done in a Java project.**

See the other answer if you're coming from a C++ background

---

In Java, You can use [sourceSets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html) to configure your sources, eg.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = [
                "$projectDir/src/main/java",
                "$projectDir/$generatedDir",
                "$projectDir/config/sql"
            ]
            include '**/*.java'
        }

        resources {
            srcDirs = [
                 "$projectDir/src/main/resources"
            ]

        }
    }

    test {
        java { srcDir 'src/test/java'}
        resources { srcDir 'src/test/resources' }
    }

    componentTest {
        java { srcDir 'src/ctest/java' }
        resources { srcDir 'src/ctest/resources' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean it as a solution for cpp projects or only java project? Your solution does not work for cpp i think. I get a "Could not find method cpp() for arguments" when i replace java with cpp. I am using the cpp plugin too (apply plugin: 'cpp' )

Comment: You asked about the custom sources, I don't know what is a `cpp` and it was not included int the question either. Please refine your question or ask a new one - a proper one.

Comment: wow! dude! where you on holiday? for 2 years? Anyway i used CMAKE instead.

Comment: If this could be changed to be compatible with the C++ plugin, it would properly address the question.

Answer (score 0):

The way that this is done with a Gradle C++ project is different than the way it's done in a Java project.

### With `cpp-application`/`cpp-library`

These plugins were [introduced in 2018](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-the-new-cpp-plugins) and are the preferred methods of building C++ projects going forward (see [full documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_cpp_projects.html)).

From the documentation on "[Customizing file and directory locations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_cpp_projects.html#sec:custom_cpp_source_set_paths)":

```
plugins {
    id 'cpp-application'
}

application {
    source.from file('src')
    privateHeaders.from file('src')
    publicHeaders.from file('include')
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'cpp-library'
}

library {
    source.from file('src')
    privateHeaders.from file('src')
    publicHeaders.from file('include')
}
```

Note that by declaring these, Gradle will only search in these directories (and not in the default location of `src/main/cpp`).

### With `cpp` plugin (deprecated)

The `cpp` plugin using the software model is an older, deprecated method of building C++ projects (see [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html#native_binaries)).

```
apply plugin: "cpp"

sources {
    cpp {
        source {
            srcDir "src"
            // Note that this reference to "include" refers to the files that should be matched in this directory and has nothing to do with the include directory
            include "**/*.cpp"
        }
        exportedHeaders {
            srcDir "include"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good stuff, I added the answer coming from Java background, thanks. The actual question should have that added. I will create an edit request